# How to pull values from URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I will have a URL like this:

`http://website/index.html?id=1234&type=something`

The id and type being passed will be different depending on what the user does on the other end.

Using Javascript, I want to get the id and the type to be used as variables, like this:

`var theID = 1234`
`var theType = something`

But I don't know how to pull those values from the URL and set the values like above. How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: @davibq - thanks, that's perfect for what I need. I don't want to pass any values into the function, and this code pulls it directly from the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function qs(url, key) {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars[key];
}

var url = YourUrl;
alert(qs(url,'id'));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/exf88/)

Answer (score 1):

My util function, its a bit dirty but gets the job done. No need to split array just few indexOf functions. If you want to utf8 decoded value use decodeURIComponent(str) or iso1 legacy decoded use decodeURI(str)

```
// parse parameter value from url (case sensitive)
function getURLParam(strURL, strKey) {
   // http://mywebapp/do.url?key1=val1&key2=val2
   var idx = strURL.indexOf('?');
   if (idx < 0) return ""; // no params

   // "&key1=val1&key2=val2&"
   strURL = "&" + strURL.substring(idx+1) + "&";
   idx = strURL.indexOf("&" + strKey + "=");
   if (idx < 0) return ""; // param not found

   // "&key1=val1&key2=val2&" -> "val1&key2=val2&" -> "val1"
   strURL = strURL.substring(idx + strKey.length + 2);
   idx = strURL.indexOf("&");    
   return strURL.substring(0, idx);
}
```